# unit conversion when importing datasets from excel files in brightway

Tags: brightway

I am trying to create some activities using the excel importer. My activity has a technosphere flow of 0.4584 MWh of `Production of electricity by gas` from the previously imported *EXIOBASE 3.3.17 hybrid* database. The activity of `Production of electricity by gas` is in TJ in the database.

I ran without problems the import, something like:

```
ei = ExcelImporter(path_to_my_excel)
ei.apply_strategies()
ei.match_database(fields = ['name','location'])
ei.match_database(db_name = 'EXIOBASE 3.3.17 hybrid', fields = ['name','location'])
ei.match_database(db_name = 'biosphere3', fields = ['name','categories'])

ei.write_project_parameters()
ei.write_database(activate_parameters=True)
```

but if I iterate over the technosphere flows of my activity consuming natural gas it says it uses 0.4584 **TJ** of `Production of electricity by gas` (the same unit as the activity of production of electricty by gas, but the same amount I put in MWh). I was kind of hoping some unit conversion under the hood. Perhaps using bw2io.units.UNITS_NORMALIZATION.

Should we always express the units of exchanges with the same units as the activity they link ? is there an existing strategy to do the unit conversion for us? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `ei.match_database(db_name = 'EXIOBASE 3.3.17 hybrid', fields = ['name','location'])` is telling the program to match, but **not** to match based on units.

You can get the desired result with a migration, see [an example here](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/IO%20-%20Importing%20Agribalyse%201.3%20with%20Ecoinvent%203.2%20cutoff.ipynb) (in the section `Fixing units for passenger cars`).

Comment: ok cool, I see in the docs (https://2.docs.brightway.dev/intro.html#importing-and-exporting) in _migrations_ some more documentation about how to do this